# Obtener la última fila de cada grupo en un dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, filtro, data, dplyr

Tengo los datos de vacunación por países y necesito el último dato disponible para el año 2021 por país.

Previamente he realizado estos comandos sobre la base de datos que dispongo:

#### Para que el último dato disponible no sea muy lejano

```
library(dplyr)

tabla1 <- filter(vacunados, date >= "2021-12-01" & date <= "2021-12-31")
```

#### Para eliminar los valores en blanco

```
tabla1 <- tabla1[!is.na(tabla1$people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred),]
```

#### Para seleccionar las variables que necesito

```
tabla1 <- select(tabla1,location, date, people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred)
```

Existen muchos países que ofrecen todos los datos para el mes de diciembre y únicamente necesito el último para cada uno de ellos, pero no conozco el comando para hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido Miguel a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Hola Miguel! Por favor dale una mirada a los textos sugeridos por Patricio Moracho. En este caso sería muy valioso que incluyeras una muestra de tus datos o un ejemplo basado en datos similares a los tuyos para facilitar que tu pregunta sea reproducida por otras personas. Para eso puedes usar la función `dput()` sobre una parte de tus datos, por ejemplo: `dput(head(datos))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es usar el paquete "data.table". Puedes utilizar `SD` para aplicar la función `which.max` a la variable `date` agrupada por `location`, de la siguiente manera:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(datos) # en caso que sea necesario transformar la tabla en "data.table"-"dataframe"

dt[, .SD[which.max(date)], location]
```

Output

```
   location       date people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred continent
1: Afghanistan 2022-02-20                               10.36      Asia
2:     Albania 2022-02-20                               41.37    Europe
3:      Zambia 2022-02-24                                9.89    Africa
```

Una opción usando `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

 dt %>%
     group_by(location) %>%
     filter(date == max(date))
```

Output

```
+ # A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   location [3]
  location    date       people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred continent
  <chr>       <date>                                   <dbl> <chr>    
1 Afghanistan 2022-02-20                               10.4  Asia     
2 Albania     2022-02-20                               41.4  Europe   
3 Zambia      2022-02-24                                9.89 Africa
```

Datos utilizados:

Tomé los datos del siguiente sitio y seleccioné una parte de ellos.

```
library(data.table)

# datos

dt <- fread('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv')

# selección de columnas

cols <- c('location', 'date', 'people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred', 'continent')

# columnas seleccionadas, eliminando datos perdidos en columna vacunación

dt1 <- dt[, ..cols][!is.na(people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred)]

# selección de países

co <- c('Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Zambia')

# seleccionando algunos países y fechas recientes

dt <- dt1[location %in% co & date >'2022-01-30', ]
```

```
structure(list(location = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Zambia", 
"Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", 
"Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", "Zambia", 
"Zambia"), date = structure(c(19023L, 19025L, 19030L, 19037L, 
19043L, 19024L, 19029L, 19030L, 19036L, 19037L, 19038L, 19039L, 
19043L, 19023L, 19026L, 19027L, 19030L, 19031L, 19032L, 19033L, 
19035L, 19037L, 19039L, 19041L, 19043L, 19044L, 19045L, 19046L, 
19047L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred = c(9.77, 
9.82, 9.94, 10.15, 10.36, 40.26, 40.62, 40.71, 41.05, 41.12, 
41.17, 41.22, 41.37, 8.78, 8.91, 8.97, 9.06, 9.1, 9.15, 9.2, 
9.29, 9.34, 9.45, 9.58, 9.67, 9.69, 9.76, 9.83, 9.89), continent = c("Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa"
)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                                       ))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he conseguido obtener. :)

Comment: Qué bien! Me alegra saber que lo conseguiste!